# Unquoted carriage return found in data - Preventing COPY FROM in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, carriage-return

I am trying to import a large csv file (~4.5gb) into Postgres but it keeps throwing the following error:

**ERROR:  unquoted carriage return found in data

HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent carriage return.

CONTEXT:  COPY abc_complete_file_261115, line 9041959**

I opened my csv in SublimeText2 and jumped to line 9041959, found the URN for record I needed, loaded the file in Vim and went to that line. I have hidden characters enabled in Vim (by using :set list) so I would expect to see a carriage return ^M somewhere on the line within the data but the only one I could find is at the end of the line as expected.

After an entire day of research and having gotten no further with this issue I ended up deleting the record on line 9041959 - this didn't fix the issue.

Then I figured well maybe it's something strange going on between records - so I ended up deleting about 5 records on either side of the line that threw the error - but it gave the the same error again. (I'll worry about preserving the data later on, right now I'm just trying to import the file so that I can have a look in Postgres). I made sure that I had saved the changes to the csv file before rerunning my query but it just gave the same error.

I feel like I am missing something really really obvious - does anyone have any ideas what might be causing the issue?

I'm using a Mac running El Capitan.

Many thanks

**Update 27/11/15**

Hi @JakubKania. Sorry for not putting up the query - the reason I didn't was because I am 99.9% sure that the issue is to do with the csv file rather than the query.  A generalised version is:

```
CREATE TABLE large_file_test(
urn VARCHAR,
forename CHAR(32),
surname CHAR(32));
COPY large_file_test FROM '/Users/Shared/largefile1.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER, ENCODING LATIN1);
COPY large_file_test FROM '/Users/Shared/largefile2.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER, ENCODING LATIN1);
COPY large_file_test FROM '/Users/Shared/largefile3.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER, ENCODING LATIN1);
ALTER TABLE large_file_test
ADD CONSTRAINT large_urn
PRIMARY KEY (large_urn);
ANALYZE large_file_test;
```

So I am actually trying to load 3 separate files into the Table that I created. The issue is that there seems to be hidden characters in part 1 that are preventing it from importing into Postgres. I haven't tried anything with part 2 or 3 yet.

Comment: Showing full command should be helpful. Also: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/c5ec4064120c12c7b8cd4772d0b9f571f5dd40b4/src/backend/commands/copy.c#L3386

Comment: Hi @Sato Katsura, I was just wondering if you could advise why this question has nothing to do with Vim? I am confident that my Postgres query is correct and the csv isn't loading into Postgres because there appears to hidden characters in the file. I need to use Vim to remove these hidden characters but can't because I can't see the hidden carriage return Postgres is talking about? I need to use Vim before I can even use Postgres therefore isn't Vim a relevant tag? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder if this is an encoding issue. Are you **sure** the file is encoded using `LATIN1` and not some multi-byte encoding?

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name - I had been wondering the very same. I tried to rerun the query but without the Latin1 part i.e. `(FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER);` and it gave me the following error   `ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd82b
SQL state: 22021
Context: COPY 123_complete_file_261115, line 18982`. I don't really have anyway to find out how it was encoded - is there a way to identify what coding was used? Many thanks

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name - managed to find out that `MS code 1252 (ANSI – Latin I)` was used to produce the file so unfortunately it looks like `Latin1` should have worked

Comment: _carriage return ^M somewhere on the line_: that's not what I would expect if ^M is the line terminator. What to expect would be a premature end of line. As you have 3 fields, the offending line could be `value-for-urn,value-for-forename`. As the third field is missing, copy would infer that the 2nd field continues to the next line, which is legit per CSV rules but only if the field is enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I found to solve this in MAC -El Capitan is:

1) Open the file with Sublime Text
2) in menu Reopen the file with encoding UTF8
3) in menu Save the file with encoding UTF8

Sublime "normalize" all end of line EOF.

Comment: Thanks a million! This saved me much frustration while up against a deadline.

Comment: Ah, but what if your process already defaults to UTF8 with the example being df.to_csv() while using the Pandas library in Python???

Answer (score 0):

This likely is caused by Windows line endings. Try installing the utility `dos2unix` and running `dos2unix <filename>` before executing the `COPY` command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I noticed that the csv file had an extra blank at the end. After removing it, the file imported properly.

Answer (score -1):

I created a separate folder and gave read/write permissions to "everybody" and that solved all this problem as well as the problem of access being denied when trying to import the file through pgAdmin4 as well. Seems to have been the "cure all".

Now, just to find out which user I need to give these permissions to instead of "everybody".

Using PostgreSQL v 9.6 on Windows 10.